# How can I clear (declutter) notification bar history?

Tags: windows, taskbar

In Taskbar settings I see plenty notification bar programs I've uninstalled, I want to clear it. I can't find where this information stored. Neither global file search or registry search helped me.

Notification bar settings:
[image: Notification bar settings]

Comment: You can see notification bar settings I mean is the screenshot attached.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Settings app? I don't know if it works, but there might be a chance.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, did't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
You can use this tool http://www.itsamples.com/notification-area-cleaner.html which claims to clean notification area from uninstalled programs for Windows 7, but works perfectly fine in Windows 10.

If you want to do it manually, notification area settings stored in
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`

Restart File Explorer after you done